# Concatenate two videos and one picture

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have 1 picture (png) and 2 videos (mp4).

Using Windows OS, I need to concatenate their: video + picture duration 5 seconds without sound + video.

How can I do it?

Comment: You've tagged the question [ffmpeg], but you don't even mention it in the question.   Have you researched FFmpeg?  What have you learned?  What have you tried?  What results have you obtained?

Comment: Are they the same resolution and framerate - the videos and the picture?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, both videos and pictures have the same resolution and framerate.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i vid1 -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 5 -i pic -i vid2 -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc
   -filter_complex
       "[0:v][0:a][1][3][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1"   out.mp4
```

The framerate for the picture should be replaced with the framerate of the videos. The `-t 5` sets the duration, in seconds, of the picture.